# JSoup - Extracting images only finds the first image

Tags: android, image, jsoup

I am currently using JSoup to pull various things off of a few websites. I'm having difficulty with images though.

The html code is something along the lines of this:

```
<div id="bK5ZEcg" class="post">
   <a class="image-list-link" href="/r/GetMotivated/bK5ZEcg" data-page="0">
     <img alt="" src="//i.imgur.com/bK5ZEcgb.jpg" original-title="">
   </a>
</div>
```

The webpage is a gallery where the same code is posted above for each image with their respective links.

I have written my code out as below, looking for images ending in **".jpg"** to find all of the images on the page and extract them into an array.

```
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Log.d("JSoup Connection", "connected...");


            //Extract images from site
            Elements elemImages = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");


            for(Element e : elemImages)
            {
                Log.d("Single Image",e.absUrl("src"));

                //Will add to array later, just trying to get output for now
                //receivedImages.add(e.absUrl("src").toString());
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("Image collect", "Images Collected");
        return receivedImages;

    }
```

When I run my code it only finds the one image on the website, despite there being numerous images to extract.

```
12-22 19:43:48.275: I/System.out(786): connected...
12-22 19:43:48.335: D/Single Image(786): http://i.imgur.com/rCjTX81l.jpg
12-22 19:43:48.335: D/Image collect(786): Images Collected
```

I've been at this for a while now debugging and trying different selection syntaxes. Could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Also forgive my sloppy coding.. I'm still getting to grips with Android development.

Thanks a bunch

EDIT: Forgot to include the website I was parsing.  http://imgur.com/r/GetMotivated

Comment: Are you sure there are more images that end with .jpg on the URL you are scrapping?

Comment: The selection syntax does exactly what you want. So don't worry about that. Could you provide the page you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to reply, I posted the question late last night. Yep sure the page is: http://imgur.com/r/GetMotivated

Comment: As a simple java application your code runs as expected. Try printing the size of `elemImages`. And then try printing the `elemImages` itself. Maybe there is a mobile version, I'll have to check with an emulator.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head there. Hadn't thought about JSoup loading up the mobile version of the site, I guess the emulator would do that as well. Checked with imgur there and they do have a mobile site. I assume that the display differs with each device. I'll try running a couple of different emulators and see what the result is and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I managed to reproduce it. If you run this on desktop, but emulating a mobile device and scraping the mobile site you get only one icon

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.imgur.com/r/GetMotivated").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30").get();
```

The solution is to specify a different user agent, that belongs to a desktop browser and scrape the desktop site, not the mobile one. Try this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://imgur.com/r/GetMotivated")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();
```

The reason as to why this is happening is due to the client html generation of the mobile site. 
Open chrome while on desktop, go to dev tools, open a mobile emulator and visit the mobile site.
Press ctrl+u, that's the html that jsoup parses, and you will see there that the content is not 
finalized, but has a lot of tags (angular?) that are useless to jsoup.

By specifying a desktop user agent you ask for the desktop version of the site, that generates the html in a different way, that is useful to jsoup. Keep in mind, jsoup will parse whatever you see by pressing ctrl+u while on chrome, nothing more.

Comment: That was the problem. I can't believe I missed that when it seems so obvious now. Won't make the same mistake twice!  Thanks again dude

Answer (score 0):

Try with "first()":

```
Elements elemImages = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
elemImages.first();
```